# Access to singleton from plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, singleton

The structure of application is that I have two Singletons. One for managing the work, one for managing the SQLite database.

The work manager loads plugins that wish to access the database. Is there anyway to give them access to the Singleton database manager? If I include the database manager class in the plugin dll - would that work?

I know the other way would be to have a field in the plugin interface and set that field on plugin load, I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it and keep my plugin architecture.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Restrictions:

- Can't use external libraries.
- The set of singleton classes that I wish to be accessible from plugins is, and always will be, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at dependency injection containers like [Castle Windows](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), [Sprint.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). These will allow you to inject your dependencies automatically or allow your plugins access to your singletons by using the containers.
I've used Castle Windsor a lot and can recommend it, but the others mentioned are also used by a lot of developers. Sorry but forget to mention the [Microsoft Unity container](http://unity.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I appreciate that this is the "best" answer, but lets say I am not worried about the extensibility and need the plugin to "see" a fixed set of singleton classes. Or that I am not allowed to use external libraries - what would the solution be?

Comment: It really depends. Do you control the plug-in development also. Having a DLL shared between the plugins which give access to the singletons using static methods is an alternative. The main point being that somewhere along the way you either need to directly inject, or make available to the plugin's the required instances. If possible you could also pass in a factory method as a delegate which returns the required singleton interface. I am presuming that your using an interface and not a direct instance of a class.